# Сворачивание функций PyCharm

Tags: ide, pycharm

Есть ли какой-то способ в PyCharm свернуть все "скобки одновременно"?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> (минус).

Развернуть всё - то же самое, только с <kbd>+</kbd>.

Можно изменить на другие сочетания в Settings - Keymap (Collapse All / Expand All).